# Asp.net mvc 301 redirect

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

I have one website with ssl certificate.
The domain is http://example.com
I have one sub domain http://api.example.com which has not ssl certificate.

So i want to redirect my http://example.com to https://example.com using web.config MVC.

When I am doing this, the subdomain is also redirect 301.

I want to redirect only my main domain.

My code is as below:

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect-HTTP-HTTPS-IIS">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" ignoreCase="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Comment: try adding another condition, something like <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.com$" ignoreCase="true" />

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<rule name="RedirectDomain" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="true">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.com$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```